# Replace every two items in a list for a respective value in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, binary

I used a program to convert an integer vector to binary, now I need to do the reverse operation, but I believe the logic I am using it's not correct.

```
population=[[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [6], [0]], 
[[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [4], [1]], 
[[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [6], [2]],
[[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [4], [3]]]

def BinaryConversion2(population):
    binary_return = []
    binary_index = {(0,0): 0, (0,1): 1, (1,0): 2, (1,1): 3}   
    for game in range (0, len(population)):
        converted = [s for num in population[game][0] for s in binary_index[num]]   
        binary_return.append(converted) 
    return (binary_return)
```

I need to replace every two bits of the binary strings in brackets for the respective dictionary value, but I believe the problem here is that the program is indexing single bits, so it is not working properly.

Does anyone know how to reference every two items in the list for the dictionary respective values? Or anything else that might be useful in this case.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for game in population:
    binary_return = [binary_index[(i,j)] for i,j in zip(game[0][0::2], game[0][1::2])]
```

Comment: Nice. Note that you don't need `binary_index`. You could simply use `2*i + j`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solution that works.

```
population=[[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [6], [0]], 
[[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [4], [1]], 
[[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [6], [2]],
[[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [4], [3]]]
binary_index = {(0,0): 0, (0,1): 1, (1,0): 2, (1,1): 3}    
#zipping
list2 = []
for i in [num[0] for num in population]:
    it = iter(i)
    list2.append(zip(it,it))   
converted = [[binary_index[s] for s in num]for num in list2]
```

With this you will get the output in same form as your population list, but I have no idea on what are two single element lists in your each entry, so i just dropped it. You can edit it if you like.

Comment: I am trying this way, but I get this error here; `File "<ipython-input-9-b5c5a38c61d6>", line 17, in BinaryConversion2
    converted = [binary_index[s] for s in num for num in list2]

NameError: name 'num' is not defined` Any thoughts?

Comment: sorry, i had small error in code. can you try the update?

Comment: well, you of course need to define your population first. so try with population list that you have above.

Comment: Now it worked, thank you very much, I guess Id never have thought in something like this!